# Why i'm facing Regex detection problem inside a loop in Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm facing very weird problem while using regex.

```
weight='abcd'
description='ml'
for symbol in Syntax['symbol']:
            print(symbol)
            weight=re.findall(symbol,description)
print(weight)
output --> []
```

***Syntax is a data frame*** that contains different units, also contains ***" ml "*** inside symbol column, i have manually printed the symbol variable it prints required unit that is ***"ml"*** which will be set as pattern in loop but still it returns [] OR None while using re.match().
But when i try code below

```
description='ml'
pattern='ml'
print(re.findall(pattern,description)
```

it prints ***"ml"***, Why ??? Both above and Top code are logically same.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        description='ml'
        weight=0
        for symbol in self.units['symbol']:
            print("units in Syntax dataframe : ",symbol)
            weight=re.findall(symbol,description)
            if weight!=[]:
                break
        print(weight)
```

I have understood the problem, i was not stopping the loop when the 'ml' is found, that's why it was printing [] or None

Answer (score 1):

In the top code, you're only printing the result of the final regex search, since `print(weight)` is outside your loop. It's all well and good if "ml" is somewhere in your data frame, but if the *last* value of `symbol` doesn't match anything in `description`, the regex won't find any matches and you won't get any output.

Try printing `weight` inside the `for` loop and see what output you get.